# How move_upload_file calls to custom stream_wrappers class

Tags: 7, stream-wrappers

In a node form, I upload a image to the server via ajax and before to send to the uri, I want to optimize the original image (not a image style).

How is possible that from move_upload_file that is a native php function calls to a custom class with hook_stream_wrappers

My uri:

> gs://my-image.jpg

From here:

```
function drupal_move_uploaded_file($filename, $uri) {
  $result = @move_uploaded_file($filename, $uri); // this function calls to custom class
  // PHP's move_uploaded_file() does not properly support streams if safe_mode
  // or open_basedir are enabled so if the move failed, try finding a real path
  // and retry the move operation.
  if (!$result) {
    if ($realpath = drupal_realpath($uri)) {
      $result = move_uploaded_file($filename, $realpath);
    }
    else {
      $result = move_uploaded_file($filename, $uri);
    }
  }

  return $result;
}
```

Calls to:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Implements DrupalStreamWrapperInterface.
 */

class OSCaddieGCSStreamWrapper implements DrupalStreamWrapperInterface {
  ....
}
```

Comment: See [`stream_wrapper_register()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-register.php)

Comment: Thanks @clive. And you know how can i upload to a CDN? with a file_move($file, "gs://my-image.jpg") ??